# XSLT to flatten XML

Tags: xml, xslt

Could anyone please help me with the following transformation?

Here is the input xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book>
    <title>My book</title>
    <pages>200</pages>
    <size>big</size>
    <author>
        <name>Smith</name>
    </author>
    <author>
        <name>Wallace</name>
    </author>
    <author>
        <name>Brown</name>
    </author>
</book>
<book>
    <title>Other book</title>
    <pages>100</pages>
    <size>small</size>
    <author>King</author>
</book>
<book>
    <title>Pretty book</title>
    <pages>150</pages>
    <size>medium</size>
</book>
```

This is the desired output

```
<book style="even">
    <title>My book</title>
    <pages>200</pages>
    <size>big</size>
    <author-name>Smith</author-name>
</book>
<book style="odd">
    <title>My book</title>
    <pages>200</pages>
    <size>big</size>
    <author-name>Wallace</author-name>
</book>
<book style="even">
    <title>My book</title>
    <pages>200</pages>
    <size>big</size>
    <author-name>Brown</author-name>
</book>
<book style="odd" >
    <title>Other book</title>
    <pages>100</pages>
    <size>small</size>
    <author-name>King</author-name>
</book>
<book style="even">
    <title>Pretty book</title>
    <pages>150</pages>
    <size>medium</size>
    <author-name />
</book>
```

I tried using `xsl:for-each` loops, but I suppose they brought me to a dead end. The tricky part here is the "style" attribute that somehow needs to be "global" no matter how many author tags are placed in any book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This stylesheet first stores all author nodes as well as all book nodes without authors in a global variable. "/." sorts them in document order. Then the main template iterates over all nodes in this variable and generates output according to the position in the sequence.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:variable name="authors" select="(//author | //book[not(author)])/."/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="result">
      <xsl:for-each select="$authors">
        <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
          <xsl:with-param name="position" select="position()+1"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()|title|pages|size">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="book">
    <xsl:param name="position" select="1"/>
    <xsl:element name="book">
      <xsl:attribute name="style">
        <xsl:if test="$position mod 2 = 0">even</xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$position mod 2 = 1">odd</xsl:if>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="title"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="pages"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="size"/>
      <xsl:element name="author-name"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="author">
    <xsl:param name="position" select="1"/>
    <xsl:element name="book">
      <xsl:attribute name="style">
        <xsl:if test="$position mod 2 = 0">even</xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$position mod 2 = 1">odd</xsl:if>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="../title"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="../pages"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="../size"/>
      <xsl:element name="author-name">
        <xsl:if test="name">
          <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="not(name)">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hmm, can't get this to work. I get the following error: "Template conflicts with another template in this stylesheet". Even if I make the transformation I only get the last book...

Comment: Sorry about that, there was a superfluous template on / that I forgot to remove, it is now corrected. It is strange though, I tried it successfully with an XSLT engine and it did not complain about this. Also, I added a root element to the input document, which might also be a reason for different behavior.

Comment: I don't know why, but this only works with Xalan processor and does not with standard processor included in JRE.

Comment: Accepted answer. The first answer and the first answer giving the exact required output. Maybe not as optimal as @Dmitre's, but looking less complicated.

Answer (score 7):

**This simple, pure XSLT 1.0 transformation (no conditionals, no `xsl:for-each`, no parameter passing, no `xsl:element`, no use of the infamously inefficient `//`)**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my" exclude-result-prefixes="my" >
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <my:names>
     <n>odd</n>
     <n>even</n>
    </my:names>

    <xsl:variable name="vStyles"
        select="document('')/*/my:names/*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="book/author">
     <xsl:variable name="vPos">
      <xsl:number level="any" count="book/author|book[not(author)]"/>
     </xsl:variable>
        <book style="{$vStyles[$vPos mod 2 +1]}">
          <xsl:copy-of select="@*|../node()[not(self::author)]"/>
          <author-name>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
      </author-name>
        </book>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="book[author]">
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="book[not(author)]">
     <xsl:variable name="vPos">
      <xsl:number level="any" count="book/author|book[not(author)]"/>
     </xsl:variable>
        <book style="{$vStyles[$vPos mod 2 +1]}">
          <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()"/>
          <author-name/>
        </book>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="book[author]/*[not(self::author)]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied to this XML document** (the provided one wrapped into a single top element):

```
<t>
    <book>
        <title>My book</title>
        <pages>200</pages>
        <size>big</size>
        <author>
            <name>Smith</name>
        </author>
        <author>
            <name>Wallace</name>
        </author>
        <author>
            <name>Brown</name>
        </author>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>Other book</title>
        <pages>100</pages>
        <size>small</size>
        <author>King</author>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>Pretty book</title>
        <pages>150</pages>
        <size>medium</size>
    </book>
</t>
```

**produces exactly the wanted, correct result**:

```
<t>
   <book style="even">
      <title>My book</title>
      <pages>200</pages>
      <size>big</size>
      <author-name>Smith</author-name>
   </book>
   <book style="odd">
      <title>My book</title>
      <pages>200</pages>
      <size>big</size>
      <author-name>Wallace</author-name>
   </book>
   <book style="even">
      <title>My book</title>
      <pages>200</pages>
      <size>big</size>
      <author-name>Brown</author-name>
   </book>
   <book style="odd">
      <title>Other book</title>
      <pages>100</pages>
      <size>small</size>
      <author-name>King</author-name>
   </book>
   <book style="even">
      <title>Pretty book</title>
      <pages>150</pages>
      <size>medium</size>
      <author-name/>
   </book>
</t>
```

**Explanation**: Appropriate use of **[`xsl:number`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#number)** and templates/pattern matching.

Comment: Almost, please note that in the output provided last book contains empty `author-name` node

Comment: Sure -- I will correct this when I get to work -- I'm just leaving home.

Comment: Thanks Dmitre for your answer (+1). I decided to accept xqib-team this time. See comment below

Comment: @VoodooRider: Updated to produce the wanted `<author-name/>`. BTW, you have accepted a longer and more complicated solution ...

Comment: @VoodooRider: Which "comment below" are you referring to?

Comment: @Treemonkey: For me the fact that there is some `xsl:if` or `xsl:choose`/`xsl:when` in the code, means that templates and pattern matching were not used appropriately.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev i have a question not really on topic but using your response as an example, you have inserted the book element in two templates, is there another way to acheive the same where you only have one?like <xsl:copy-of select="$book"><author-name>fred</author-name></xsl:copy-of>

Comment: @Treemonkey: Yes, this can be refactored, so that there is a single template matching `book` and it accepts a parameter the `author` child of the matched element -- I am not quite sure if this is better than my current solution, and the code is quite short to deserve this additional refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

(revised)

```
<xsl:for-each "//author | /book[not(author)]" />
  <xsl:variable name="style" select="('even','odd')[(position() mod 2) + 1]" />
  <xsl:apply-templates select="."><xsl:with-param name="style" select="$style" /></xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Then in your author template you can construct the book elements using ..

Comment: That wouldn't pick up "Pretty Book", as there is no author

Comment: ('even','odd')[(position() mod 2) + 1] is not a valid XPath expr

Comment: I think it might require XPath 2